# Efficient Tag Management?

Tags: tags, workflow

I am the admin for a blog with around 20 authors contributing articles.
Have just migrated from Wordpress.com.

The problem that started to happen at WP.com, was different authors would use tags differently.
i.e Some would pick just basic tags, others would list out every key word possible.

It would appear that for WP roles, all the ones that allow people to submit posts, they can also tag their posts with as many tags as they want.

So, my question is - **What is best practice for Tag Management for a blog that has multiple authors?**
- I guess the answer to this could be subjective.  But I really need experienced advice on this, and Wordpress-Answers is where I am going to find this.
- Happy to convert to Community Wiki?

Comment: Are you searching for a plugin, or a code solution (can you write code)?

Comment: I think it might be more of a "best practices" sort of question, for which the implementation might be procedural, or might be code-based (i.e. via Plugin)?

Comment: Took some of the waffle out of my Q.  If their are plugins that make tag mgmt easier, then they can be included in an answer.  But yes to Chip - looking for the best practise around tag mgmt. Even sites like this WP-Answers, only users who have earned rep can create new tags.  
My idea is that Editors should be able to create tags, Authors shouldnt.

Comment: Use custom capabilities with a custom taxonomy, like i mentioned [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/14344/1468)? So you could set the required cap to create terms to something only an editor can do, whilst keeping term assignment on a lower cap for authors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage a blog with 3 editors and 8-10 contributors.

In my experience, the best way to manage tags is to simply instruct contributors not to add tags to their own articles, and instead have the editors be responsible for tagging articles. You can then work with editors to agree on what the purpose of tags are on for your site and make sure they enforce those policies.

I use the [Simple Tags](https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-tags/) plugin for adding tags to articles which replaces the default tag entry system. When you type in a tag, it automatically searches existing tags and displays them in an AJAX-y dropdown display, which is very helpful to avoid dupes and to see what similar tags exist.

I hadn't always managed tags so diligently, so I used the [Terms Management Tool](https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/term-management-tools/) plugin to merge similar/duplicate tags together. We had a lot of things like "Firefox" and "Mozilla Firefox", so I combined those into a single tag, and Simple Tags helps avoid problems like that in the future.